# Agent error when launching instance with OpenStack Icehouse

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, ubuntu-14.04

I have encountered the following error in nova compute logs when launching a new instance with OpenStack Icehouse:

```
"AgentError: Error during following call to agent: 
['ovs-vsctl', '--timeout=120', 'del-port', 'br-int', u'qvoe75657b1-b5']\n"]
```

The selected image is Ubuntu Server Trusty Tahr.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The selected flavor disk was too small as indicated by this bug report
https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/1326566

After selecting a flavor of type `m1.small`, everything went smoothly